# How to match IP addresses in a comma-separated string

Tags: python, regex, ip

Code show as below, but there is a problem: **"255.255.255.256" will be processed into "255.255.255.25"**

```py
import re

ip_pattern = re.compile(r"((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)")

def get_ip_by_regex(ip_str):
    """Match IP from the given text and return

    :param ip_str: like "255.255.255.255,255.255.255.256,260.255.255.255"
    :type ip_str: string
    :return: IP LIST ["255.255.255.255"]
    :rtype: list[string]
    """
    ret = []
    for match in ip_pattern.finditer(ip_str):
        ret.append(match.group())
    return ret
```

If I pass the `255.255.255.255,255.255.255.256,260.255.255.255` string I expect `["255.255.255.255"]` as the results.

Comment: `patt = re.compile(r'\b\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\b')`

Comment: But I want to remove invalid ip like 256.256.256.256

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the exact problem that you are trying to solve? Please post sample inputs and outputs to indicate the type of patterns that are valid or invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to implement **comma boundaries**, `(?<![^,])` and `(?![^,])`:

```py
ip_pattern = re.compile(r"(?<![^,])(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)(?![^,])")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DZf6wz/1/).

*Details*

- `(?<![^,])` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location not immediately preceded with a char other than a comma (i.e. there must be a comma or start of string immediately to the left of the current location)
- `(?![^,])` - a negative lookahead that matches a location not immediately followed with a char other than a comma (i.e. there must be a comma or end of string immediately to the right of the current location).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/8bPSOj):

```py
import re

ip_pattern = re.compile(r"(?<![^,])(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)(?![^,])")

def get_ip_by_regex(ip_str):
    """Match IP from the given text and return

    :param ip_str: like "255.255.255.255,255.255.255.256,260.255.255.255"
    :type ip_str: string
    :return: IP LIST ["255.255.255.255"]
    :rtype: list[string]
    """
    return ip_pattern.findall(ip_str)

print(get_ip_by_regex('255.255.255.255,255.255.255.256,260.255.255.255'))
# => ['255.255.255.255']
```

Comment: Thank you, I also adopted this plan in the end

Answer (score 0):

You forgot splitting. To avoid overlapping, I suggest split first. Then you can `match` or `finditer`.
Here's correct IP pattern with finding logic:

```
r"(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"


def get_ip_by_regex(ip_str):
    """Match IP from the given text and return

    :param ip_str: like "255.255.255.255,255.255.255.256,260.255.255.255"
    :type ip_str: string
    :return: IP LIST ["255.255.255.255"]
    :rtype: list[string]
    """
    ret = []
    for p in ip_str.split(','):
        for match in ip_pattern.finditer(ip_str):
            ret.append(match.group())
    return ret
```

Comment: I wanna use a single regular expression to solve it, but it not work。To solve "255.255.255.256", your code doesn't work either。

Answer (score 0):

With word boundaries:

```
import re

ip_pattern = re.compile(r"\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\b")

def get_ip_by_regex(ip_str):
    """Match IP from the given text and return

    :param ip_str: like "255.255.255.255,255.255.255.256,260.255.255.255"
    :type ip_str: string
    :return: IP LIST ["255.255.255.255"]
    :rtype: list[string]
    """
    ret = []
    for match in ip_pattern.finditer(ip_str):
        ret.append(match.group())
    return ret

print(get_ip_by_regex("255.255.255.255,255.255.255.256,260.255.255.255"))
```

[**Python code**](https://tio.run/##lVBNa8MwDL37VwifbOhCli49BEbPhQ0G2y0JJa2V1KxxjKuOhnW/PXOSdmt7GMxgS9bHe9KzLW0aM@06XdvGEThkTNulLYjQGXj0gWDd1FZvUTierYSI4jS8i/Nj5M1DnqljGt7n80xlai6zQH5Ov/4uWXHJmMISKqSlp1q1S4cVHoT3d@RkwsAfzvlzQesNLF6gdE0NtEGo9AcaIDwQFEb50WjvDBvqE1u4ooYRI4GtfkfgURwHF3dy/Z9Noll4mecjErUWf4D8o001Jka@pB/pafH6BuktAc9PhT1EP8SO0hEgPy81WA/klU3HYNk4qIdVtYFf6YNSG6W9d63LqT0orEWjxNAYVK7ZWyHlGdxP2RvGrOcmcSv0v3WRsuu@AQ)